# Error handling prioritization

Tags: fine-uploader

Is there anyway to change the priority of the various error handling messages?

There are cases where more than 1 error message applies. For instance:
If I now select one file that has the wrong file extension, it shows me the error message that I haven't selected enough files (0), instead of showing the error message with the wrong file extension.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way to change the order of the internal validation checks.  However, that is not the problem.  What you are describing sounds like a bug that may have been fixed in a recent version.  Please upgrade to the latest version.  If you are still seeing the issue, file a bug in the github project's issue tracker with steps required to reproduce.

Comment: I am using 4.4.0, so it must still be a bug

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce with 4.4.0.  Please file a bug report with specific reproduction steps.